# Dynamic table is not updating when used in Flask, but works properly otherwise

Tags: javascript, flask, vue.js

this is my HTML code

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script src="{{url_for('static', filename='login.js')}}"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.6/moment.min.js"></script>                       
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.6/locale/pl.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/ggg4zmxzjgz4i9b/style.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="app">
<div class="col-xs-5" id="mail_div">
    <label for="mail">Mail:</label>
    <input v-model="mail" placeholder="Adres e-mail:" type="text" class="form-control" id="mail">
</div>
<div class="col-xs-5" id="date_div">
    <label for="date">Data:</label>
    <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
    <input v-model="date" placeholder="Wybierz datę:" type='text' class="form-control" />
    <span class="input-group-addon">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
    </span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-5" id="adress_div">
    <label for="adress">Adres:</label>
    <input v-model="adress" placeholder="Podaj adres:"type='text' class="form-control" id="adress">
</div> 
<div class="col-xs-5" id="company_div">
    <label for="company">Firma:</label>
    <input v-model="company" placeholder="Podaj firmę:"type='text' class="form-control" id="company">
</div> 
<div class="col-xs-5" id="fliers_div">
    <label for="fliers">Ulotki:</label>
    <input v-model="fliers" placeholder="Wpisz liczbę ulotek:" type='number' class="form-control" id="fliers">   
</div>    
<div id="table">
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <th scope="col">Mail</th>
        <th scope="col">Data</th>
        <th scope="col">Adres</th>
        <th scope="col">Firma</th>
        <th scope="col">Ulotki</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {% for item in rowData %}
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">{{ item.mail }}</th>
          <td>{{ item.date }}</td>
          <td>{{ item.adress }}</td>
          <td>{{ item.company }}</td>
          <td>{{ item.fliers }}</td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
<div id="button">
    <div id="button_container_1">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" @click="addItem">Dodaj dane</button>
    </div>
    <div id="button_container_2">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Pobierz dane</button>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<script src="{{url_for('static', filename='script.js')}}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {
        $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({locale:'pl'});
    });

</script>
</body>
```

And my script.js

```
var app = new Vue({
 el: '#app',
 template:'',
 data: {
 mail:'',
 date:'',
 adress:'',
 company:'',
 fliers:'',
 rowData:[] 
 },
 methods:{
  addItem(){
  var my_object = {
    mail:this.mail,
    date:this.date,
    adress:this.adress,
    company:this.company,
    fliers:this.fliers
  };
  this.rowData.push(my_object)

  this.mail = '';
  this.date = '';
  this.adress = '';
  this.company = '';
  this.fliers = '';
}
}
})
```

When I open this on localhost after running Flask, it doesn't insert any rows in the table after clicking blue button. The same feature works when I just open the .html file (no Flask), of course with the change of script.js reference. I see no errors in the console, even when I press the button, so I don't think it's an issue with button properties. You can also see that the value in the form disappears after pressing the button. The button works, so I think that I should change something in Vue.js components, but I don't know what.

Comment: can you just confirm once you pasted the correct code here? I just copied both the code and tries to run in browser after removing the ref to the login.js and linking teh script js directly...it seems to throw errors

Comment: I am really confused here.... shouldn't the for loop be in `v-for`?? what is {% syntax %}???

Comment: I'd try to explain. I've checked this one and it's indeed not working. What was working was the slightly different code, which used v-for. However v-for apparently can't be used with Flask's Jinja resulting in fatal error. This syntax helped me avoid the fatal error, but still not giving the proper result. So to clarify, this code apparently should work in Flask, after running app.py and login on localhost.

Answer (score 0):

I already have a working solution. I've ditched using a "{{ ... }}" syntax, which conflicts with Flask and put my "item.(...)" components in "v-text" tag instead.

Comment: cool!! not really a flask guy so i got really confused with it :P